# Do verbs change form when you turn tag questions into non-tag questions?

Tags: grammar, tag-questions

When changing a tag question, for example:

> It's only you who **have** that book, isn't it?

to a non-tag question:

> Isn't it only you who **have** that book?

Does the verb stay the same?

Comment: I have edited your question as it was proofreading before, or at least it was not clear; this is the only question that I see arising, apart from something like asking how to change tag questions into non-tag questions which might be too broad for this format. Please edit the question if you feel it does not address your concerns, but make sure the question can be answered **and** has value to future visitors.

Comment: Same question was posted in ELU: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/207108/is-this-sentence-grammatically-correct-isnt-it-only-you-who-have-that-book

Comment: In either tag, the subordinate clause, *who has the book, who* is singular. The pronoun, *you*, is the only pronoun followed by a plural verb. Why? I don't know. But *who* is used in place of *he* or *she*. So the singular verb would be *has*.

Comment: Thinking through my above post, I didn't explain it very well. In the subordinate clause, the candidates would all be third person singular.

Answer (score 2):

No, the sentence is not grammatically correct. I'd word the question, "Aren't you the only one that has the book?" The subordinate clause, *that has the book* refers back to the singular pronoun, *one*, not *you*, so the singular verb, *has*, should be used.

Comment: I would first want to know whether the "you" being addressed is a singular "you" or plural "you".!

Comment: As a nit pick, shouldn't it be "Aren't you the only one WHO has the book?"?